For US humanities TT faculty apps, should I use current faculty members' titles when referring to them?
When applying for a TT job in a cross-disciplinary humanities program, it seems important that I describe potential collaborations with current faculty members in the program.
Should I refer to potential collaborators as "Prof. Firstname Lastname" or just "Firstname Lastname?" For example, "There could be some kind of intersection between my work in X and Prof. Jane Smith's work in Y."
I worry that if I include titles, I cast myself as junior and therefore underqualified.
But if I exclude titles, I fear I'll appear disrespectful.

Just opinion, of course, but I'd suggest using the titles. Either academic titles or degree designations.
I doubt that anyone would consider you unqualified for such things. Peers can use titles in written communication, or communication with others. In fact, even speaking with "Jane", they might be "Doc", as I often did with peers. Or "Prof", especially with someone recently promoted.

The critical point is to be unambiguous. When you are a colleague you may use name-only for people you work with. When you are writing to people you don't know, about people you don't know, it's better to be clear about exactly which FirstName LastName you are talking about: the Professor, or some random with the same name.
